# Django Multiple select field validation

Tags: python, django, select, view

The problem is that I have a couple of Multiple select fields in my form class and they cannot pass *is_valid* method in a view.py.

**Forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form) : 
LIMIT_OPTIONS = (('5', '5'),
                ('10', '10'),
                ('15', '15'),
                ('20', '20'))
keyword = forms.CharField(max_length=50)    
limit = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=LIMIT_OPTIONS)
```

**View.py**

```
class IndexView(View) : 
form_class = SearchForm
template_name = 'web/index.html'
def get(self, request) :
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

def post (self, request) : 
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = '****'

        keyword = form.cleaned_data['keyword']
        limit = form.cleaned_data['limit']

        userupload = {'keyword': keyword, 'limit': limit}

        response = requests.post(url, json = userupload)

        return HttpResponse(response)
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Error</h1>')
```

if I change `MultipleChoiceField` to `CharField` than everything is fine...

I was looking in the Internet and couldn't find any relative answer...

**NOTE:** I don't use any database or models (just in case if it is important)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to have Drop Down Select Field in you forms.py and [Widget - Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#select) does not pass validation (`is_valid` method)

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form) : 
LIMIT_OPTIONS = (('5', '5'),
                ('10', '10'),
                ('15', '15'),
                ('20', '20'))
    limit = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=LIMIT_OPTIONS)
```

Just change it to general `CharField` and add `widget=forms.Select(choices=LIMIT_OPTIONS)`

Example:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form) : 
LIMIT_OPTIONS = (('5', '5'),
                ('10', '10'),
                ('15', '15'),
                ('20', '20'))
    limit = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=LIMIT_OPTIONS))
```

Answer (score 1):

The default widget for MultipleChoiceField is [SelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple).

> Similar to Select, but allows multiple selection: ...

You have changed that in your form to `forms.Select`. Hence the result.

Comment: year, but there is another problem if I use SelectMultiple it changes drop down field to List field ...

Comment: So what HTML field do you want?

Comment: Drop down box is the best choice for me  =)

Comment: Is there a difference between list and drop down?

Comment: that has nothing to do with django. Use CSS for that. My answer as it stands solves the original problem you described

Comment: Good idea, thanks @VladimirDanilov  =) but had to change a bit `forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=PLACE_OPTIONS))`

Comment: If it is interesting for you, I finally found solution. Check out my answer.

Comment: yes, that's certainly an interesting way of doing it  though rather unconventional! According to the rules, you are allowed to accept your own answer so please do that and someone else may find it usefull